# view query alter : Subselects/query don't work with out brackets

Tags: users, views, database

I was trying to alter a view query with a subselect that looks like:

```
$subquery1 = (db_select('users_roles', 'r')
   ->where('r.uid = users_node__users_roles.uid and r.rid=10'));
$subquery1->addExpression('COUNT(r.rid)', 'rid');
$query->add_where(1,'1', $subquery1, '<>');
```

where $query is the main query.
But when i run the view, the query

> ...AND (1 <> SELECT COUNT(r.rid) AS rid FROM users_roles r WHERE 
>   (r.uid = users_node__users_roles.uid and r.rid=10))...

if i put brackets for the sub select query it will working fine.
ie;

> ...AND (1 <> (SELECT COUNT(r.rid) AS rid FROM users_roles r WHERE 
>   (r.uid = users_node__users_roles.uid and r.rid=10)))...

So my question is;
How can i put the subquery inside brackets?
sorry if my question is stupid?

Thanks in advance,
PREM

Comment: i found a soln; put NOT IN instead of <>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found the soln myself; put NOT IN instead of <>.
NOT IN will make the value part inside the brackets